# Laravel Ajax route issue (404 response)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, routes

Im having an issue with the route in Laravel 5 returning 404 when i use ajax requests.
Everything work **locally** but when i uploaded it through git on the laravel forge server, it returns 404, as if the routes file didnt get uploaded.
So i got a SFTP and checked, and the file did indeed get uploaded.

Controller:

```
public function getNewAjaxPosts(){
    $post = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(16);
    return view('/pages.ajax-loaded-view', array('post' => $post))->render();
}

public function getNewAjaxTrending($page){
    $return = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT *, count(views.video_id) as visningar FROM posts,views WHERE posts.id = views.video_id AND 
          posts.created_at >= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
          GROUP BY posts.id order by visningar DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET :page"),["page" => $page]);

    return View::make('/pages.ajax-load-trending', array('trending' => $return))->render();
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/ajax/posts', "VideoController@getNewAjaxPosts");

Route::get('/ajax/trending/page/{page}',"VideoController@getNewAjaxTrending");
```

Javascript file:

```
function getNewPosts(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/posts?page=' + page
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data != "") {



            $('.ajax-container').append(data);


        } else {
            $(window).unbind("scroll");
            $(".ajax-container").append("<div class='endofstream'> <i class='fa fa-paper-plane' aria-hidden='true'></i> Du har tittat igenom allt! Vad kul. glöm inte att kolla in oss på facebook </div>")
        }
    });
}

function getNewPostsTrend(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/trending/page/' + page * 15 + "/"
    }).done(function(data) {



        $('.ajax-trending').append(data);


    });
} // This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
    of_beautifier();
} else {
    var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
}
```

IF you want to see the live example:

http://www.sportmossa.se

The event triggers once you scroll down to footer(ish) And the console will logg the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

My route was cached, duuh... so the answer was artisan route:cache

Hope this might help someone else someday.

Take care!